# Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websecurity

Im setting my web security in my project , but i see an error.
this is the error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]:
>   BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting
>   constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.security.access.method.MethodSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Factory method 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: In the composition of
>   all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually
>   activated     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:721)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:534)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>   [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]     at
>   com.supermarket.SupermarketApplication.main(SupermarketApplication.java:19)
>   [classes/:na]

my cod is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService usersecurityservice;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
        return SecurityUtility.passwordEncoder();
    }
    private static final String[]PUBLIC_MATCHES = {
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/img/**",
            "/signUp",
            "/",
            "/newUser",
            "/forgetPassword",
            "/login",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/bookshelf/**",
            "/bookDetail/**",
            "/hours",
            "/faq",
            "/searchByCategory",
            "/searchBook"

    };
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity   http)throws Exception{
    http
    .authorizeRequests().
    /*antMatchers("/**").*/
    antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHES).
    permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

http
    .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
    .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
    .successForwardUrl("/login")
    .and()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout").deleteCookies("remember-me").permitAll()
    .and()
    .rememberMe();

}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal (AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(usersecurityservice).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
}
```

}
userSecurity class is:

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired()
    private UserRepository userRepository;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{

    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error acoured hear:");
    }
    User user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(null==user){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    return user;
}
```

When i delete '@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity' annotation program run correctly
I had used this cod before and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you update spring recently? In previous versions it was ok to have a null `MethodSecurityMetadataSource`, but now they added [this check](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.1.5.RELEASE/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java#L367) where if you don't have at least one method security metadata source enabled, they throw the exception that you are getting ("In the composition of all global method configuration, no annotation support was actually activated"). This happened to me when I updated from spring 5.0.7 to 5.1.5. Here is [the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5341) where this change was discussed

To fix it, either enable one of the metadata sources in the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation properties, or, if like me, you are using some kind of `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`, make sure the method `customMethodSecurityMetadataSource` returns not-null

Comment: It is solution!

Answer (score 5):

You are having this issue because you have not annotation correctly. You should add it like this: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: This worked, but can you please share why this works?

Comment: @A.R.H i really doubt that you need this anymore, but i came to this answer and had the same question and found th e answer here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security: he prePostEnabled property enables Spring Security pre/post annotations.
The securedEnabled property determines if the Secured annotation should be enabled.
The jsr250Enabled property allows us to use the RoleAllowed annotation.