# Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor': @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, perf4j

I am getting:

> Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE] 
>       error when trying to add per4j in the basic spring-boot app

So I have been trying to add perf4j logs to my spring boot app. 
Here I have set the java 8 in maven.

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

And in my local as well I have only Java 8 installed. When I run the application after adding changes for perf4j, it throws the above error. When I go deep down to the error I could see:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above

Similar issue is already there [Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549415/error-creating-bean-with-name-projectingargumentresolverbeanpostprocessor)
but with no solution.

Here is the detailed error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectingArgumentResolverBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/web/config/ProjectingArgumentResolverRegistrar.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
>           at com.calamp.connect.ae.Application.main(Application.java:29)  [classes/:na]
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
>           at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317) ~[aspectjtools-1.6.2.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:227) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.obtainPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:177) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:225) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:288) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:320) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:126) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:76) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:352) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:304) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1703) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
>           ... 15 common frames omitted

I have added the below dependencies for adding perf4j logging in pom.xml, if this could give any clue to anybody:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.16</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjtools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The error should not come, and the app should run.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://coderwall.com/p/8tbjdg/aspectj-complaining-about-java-5-compliance-level

The above link is a gem. 
It was a version issue, I upgraded the version of aspect to

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>

And it worked.
```